# Show genre labels from movies

Tags: php, laravel

I have a structure like below, there are movies and for each movie the genres and some other info that is not relevant for the question.

The dump:

```
dd($moviesInformation['movies']['data']);
```

shows:

```
^ array:8 [▼
  0 => array:22 [▶]
  1 => array:22 [▼
    "id" => 75
    "name" => array:1 [▼
      "label" => "movie title"
    ]
        "genres" => array:2 [▼
          "data" => array:32 [▼
            0 => array:3 [▼
              "id" => 64
              "name" => array:1 [▼
                "label" => "Comedy"
              ]
              "on_request" => 1
            ]
            1 => array:3 [▼
              "id" => 65
              "name" => array:1 [▼
                "label" => "Action"
              ]
              "on_request" => 1
            ]
            2 => array:3 [▶]
            3 => array:3 [▶]
            4 => array:3 [▶]
            5 => array:3 [▶]
          ]
          "meta" => array:1 [▶]
        ]
     ...
      ]
      2 => array:22 [▶]
      3 => array:22 [▶]
      4 => array:22 [▶]
      5 => array:22 [▶]
      6 => array:22 [▶]
      7 => array:22 [▶]
```

The output should be just the unique values of all movies for genres separated by "," like for example:

```
Comedy, Action, ...
```

But I'm not understanding how to properly achieve that. Do you know how it can be?

Comment: Genre is an array, you need to perform a loop on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is you are not treating `genre` like an array in your example and also missing the nested `data` array.

Collections will make this logic far more readable. This should give you a comma separated strings of genres.

```
collect(data_get($moviesInformation, 'genres.data', []))
  ->map(function ($genre) {
    return data_get($genre, 'name.label');
  })->implode(', ')
```

Screenshot in Tinkerwell of the output.

[image: working example]

Comment: Thanks! Like that it works fine. That dot syntax you are using like "genres.data" can you explain how it is or say what's' the name of the thing to learn about it? Thanks!!

Comment: Sure. `data_get()` is a helper method like `Arr::get` that can parse arrays based on dot notation. The best part is that it is null safe and takes a 3rd parameter as to the default if it finds nothing https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-data-get